# Getting instance name with grep and regex

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have this output in my shell by typing the command `foobar`:

```
NAME                                               ZONE            STATUS   ACTION  LAST_ERROR
foobar--docker-worker-yyb55u-4ivg  europe-west1-c  RUNNING  NONE
```

I want to grep the complete name. Which I try doing like this:

`$ foobar | grep -q -P "(foobar--[^\s]+)"` but this returns me: `foobar--docker-worker-yyb55u-4ivg  europe-west1-c  RUNNING  NONE`

Which I don't understand because I tested the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/sX471v/1

Any advice is welcome, thanks!

Comment: You seem to neet the `-o` option to only get the match value. Try replacing `-P` with `-oP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` display the full line where a match occurs by default. Use its `-o` option to prevent this behaviour and display the match only.
You also need to remove the `-q` "quiet" option which removes all output :

```
foobar | grep -Po "(foobar--[^\s]+)"
```